# Using boolean fields in groovy script in elasticsearch - doc['field_name'].value not working

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, boolean

**The problem**

I am trying to use boolean fields in a script to score. It seems like doc['boolean_field'].value can't be manipulated as a boolean, but _source.boolean_field.value can (even though the Scripting documentation [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) says "The native value of the field. For example, if its a short type, it will be short.").

**What I've tried**

I have a field called 'is_new'.  This is the mapping:

```
PUT /test_index/test/_mapping
{
  "test": {
    "properties": {
      "is_new": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have some documents:

```
PUT test_index/test/1
{
    "is_new": true
}

PUT test_index/test/2
{
    "is_new": false
}
```

I want to do a function_score query that will have a score of 1 if new, and 0 if not:

```
GET test_index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "<<my script>>",
            "lang": "groovy"
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

Scripts work when I use the _source.is_new.value field, but don't if I use doc['is_new'].value.

This works:

```
"if ( _source.is_new) {1} else {0}"
```

These don't work:

```
"if ( doc['is_new'].value) {1} else {0}" (always true)

"if ( doc['is_new'].value instanceof Boolean) {1} else {0}" (value isn't a Boolean)

"if ( doc['is_new'].value.toBoolean()) {1} else {0}"  (always false)

"if ( doc['is_new']) {1} else {0}"  (always true)
```

I've checked the value, and it thinks it is a string, but I can't do string comparison:

```
"if ( doc['is_new'].value instanceof String) {1} else {0}"  (always true)

"if ( doc['is_new'].value == 'true') {1} else {0}"  (always false)

"if ( doc['is_new'].value.equals('true')) {1} else {0}" (always false)
```

Is this broken, or am I doing it wrong?  Apparently it is faster to use doc['field_name'].value, so if possible, it would be nice if this worked.

I am using Elasticsearch v1.4.4.

Thanks!
Isabel

Comment: Uff I've got the same problem right now. Is there anyone who knows how to fix this issue? I've tried also doc['myField'].value.toBoolean() == true without success, I'm using Elasticsearch 1.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having the same issue on ElasticSearch v1.5.1: Boolean values in the document show up as characters in my script, T' for true and 'F' for false:

`if ( doc['is_new'].value == 'T') {1} else {0}`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! At least there is a way of checking the value of a boolean field using the doc['FIELD'].value way.

Answer (score 2):

I've just got it!

First, it works only with _source.myField, not with doc['myField'].value.
I think there's a bug there because the toBoolean() method should return a boolean depending on the actual value, but it doesn't.

But I also needed to declare the mapping of the field explicitly as boolean and not_analyzed.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm, yeah it is looking like its a bug. Yeah I did find that to work, and that is what I am using at the moment, but the documentation mentions it's more performant use doc['myField'].value rather than _source, so I was hoping I could get that working somehow.

Comment: Thanks @David! This helped me out with Elasticsearch 2.1.1.